# syntax error while using CASCADE in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

when i am trying to run following query in sqlite in android i am getting error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "autoincrement": syntax error (code 1):
```

follwing is the table creating query , i am not be able to figure out where things are going wrong

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS template_info
 (  _id integer autoincrement , 
    temp_contact_key integer , 
    temp_text text , 
    FOREIGN KEY ( temp_contact_key ) REFERENCES contact_info ( _id ) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE  ON DELETE CASCADE ,  
    PRIMARY KEY ( _id , temp_contact_key )
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL syntax problems:

- If you want to use `autoincrement`, it should be `primary key`. Either make the `_id integer primary key autoincrement` and remove the last line composite `PRIMARY KEY` (and the `,` comma before it), or remove the `autoincrement` keyword. If you need to enforce that `(_id,temp_contact_key)` pairs are unique, add `UNIQUE(_id,temp_contact_key)` constraint.
- Remove the `,` before `ON UPDATE CASCADE  ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: i want to use composite key but with autoincrement

Comment: That's not really possible but maybe you can achieve what you want with a UNIQUE constraint. Edited the answer.